# COM event handling in C++

Tags: c++, com

**Without** the following:

- ATL
- MFC

**Question:**

- How to get the COM **Server**, to report back to the COM **Client**, once a particular event has terminated?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** [**COM** event handling - IConnectionPointContainer - illustration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/TEventHandler.aspx?fid=133954&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=None&select=2755820#xx2755820xx)

Answer (score 0):

Use IConnectionPointContainer